# Identifying what material this ceiling is made out of

Tags: ceiling, plaster

I am in the process of re-modelling my old bathroom and I had the ceiling removed today. It wasn't until I put the debris in the skip that I thought I have no idea what sort of material is inside it so I don't know if I'm even allowed to put it in the skip.

I took the one piece I put in the skip out and put it to one side just in case. My brother also grinded through it using an angle grinder with no ppe.

Is there something I should do to minimize my risk of anything bad I.E throw away clothes I was wearing if the material contains asbestos or something. I have uploaded a picture of the stuff.

Can I send it to a lab in the post providing it is securely wrapped or would I have to drop it off myself if I were to have it tested?

[image: old ceiling]

Comment: There is no way to tell by looking either live or via a photo.  The only way to know is to have it tested.  You should have it tested and if positive for asbestos, have it professionally removed.

Comment: You have to get it tested to know. I don't think it's very expensive. Check with your local building department, they often have a list of local labs

Comment: Yeah I have found this site https://asbestos-surveys.org.uk/product/asbestos-testing-sample-sent-to-us/. I would need to buy the kit and purchase the testing service which I'll do shortly. It doesn't specify how it gets there. Is there normally an option to post it? There is no local testers near me so this looks like the best option for me.

Answer (score 1):

If it HAS asbestos after the grinding and removing the entire area and all ventilation in and out of the area is completely contaminated so it's a little late.

Remember that "in the olden days" a lot of people were exposed to asbestos on occasion but the people who were harmed by it had repeated exposure over many years.  People would build homes with this stuff, when they were done the home was completely contaminated, then a month later a new family would move in and nobody got sick.  With the air exchange in and out of those older structures it did not matter after a 6 months or so there was not a free asbestos fiber left.

Something tells me you knew all this already though and you are just looking for confirmation that you won't drop dead a month after you drywall everything.  Well sorry I can't give it to you - although MOST people who got sick from asbestos needed many years exposure there's always some outliers in anything.  Just try not to build a home that is so sealed up when you open the front door your ears pop and you will probably be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I am sort of aware of the dangers of asbestos but I didn't think about it being in the plaster until well after it was cut up and removed. To be fair, I'm absolutely petrified by it so I'm sort of surprised myself that I didn't think about it before or during removal. I think I have found a place where I can get some of the plaster tested for peace of mind. Also, the plaster was being cut from above as the bitumen roof had been removed. As this was sort of outside, am I correct in saying this would act as ventilation, so I am less likely to have inhaled some if it were asbestos?